# What is the difference between action editor and dope sheet?

Tags: animation

They look really similar and the timeline is too.  When I insert keyframes, they appear in both editors and the timeline.

I know one probably overlooks the other, plus there is an action editor for shape keys too.  Are there any specific documentation of what each should be used for?

Comment: Have you tried the blender manual? (yes, there is such a thing, and is not a video!) https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/index.html

Comment: yes sometimes I wonder why they don't merge Timeline and Dope Sheet, and in Dope Sheet why there is the need for Action Editor and Dope Sheet, there must be a reason why sometimes you need them separate, that said Pablo Vazquez was talking about merging Timeline and Dope Sheet, and not anymore, so I guess it's not ridiculous to imagine that they could be all in one...

Comment: it's horseshit, and confusing, I am actualy trying to understand the difference between dopesheet, timeline and action editor...and I have been using blender and doing animations for years now

Comment: no wonder why this question has no answers, nobody knows

Comment: I mean it's not that bad.  A lot of stuff in blender doesn't make sense but doesn't stop you from just using just the action editor and making what you want.  Based on what I know, Dope sheet gives you control over every object on the scene while action editor only gives you control of only 1 object.